# Ordenação de vetor por função em C

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro

Bom dia! Estou tendo problema em passar um vetor para função void para que a ordenação seja feita e retornada, assim como, problema para passar para uma outra função void cujo o proposito é exibir o vetor já organizado.

O compilador retorna esse erro:

warning: passing arument i of 'OrdenarVetor' makes pointer from integer without a cast
warning: passing arument i of 'ExibiVetor' makes pointer from integer without a cast

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>


void OrdernarVetor(int *vetorN, int tamanho)
{
    int i, j;
    int aux;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if(vetorN[i] > vetorN[j])
            {
                aux = vetorN[i];
                vetorN[i] = vetorN[j];
                vetorN[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}

void ExibirVetor(int *vetorN, tamanho)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%i", vetorN[i];)
    }
}



    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

        int i;
        int vetorN[5];

        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            printf("Insira valor da posição [%i]", i);
            scanf("%i", &vetorN[i]);
        }

        OrdernarVetor(*vetorN, 5); ExibirVetor();
    }
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>


void OrdernarVetor(int vetorN[], int tamanho)
{
int i, j;
int aux;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if(vetorN[i] > vetorN[j])
        {
            aux = vetorN[i];
            vetorN[i] = vetorN[j];
            vetorN[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    }
}

void ExibirVetor(int vetorN[], int tamanho)
{
int i;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%i", vetorN[i]);
}
}



main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int i;
    int vetorN[5];

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Insira valor da posição [%i]", i);
        scanf("%i", &vetorN[i]);
    }

    void OrdernarVetor(); 
    void ExibirVetor();
}
```

ve se isto resolve o teu problema, se tiver correto eu explico-te o que tinhas de errado.

Comment: O programa não quebrou como costumava fazer mas não me retornou o vetor organizado

Comment: também estou com problemas na organização desculpa xD

Comment: Um colega da faculdade me apontou o erro. Deixo para consulta de quem estiver com dúvidas similares.

Answer (score 0):

O erro no código citado acima era na passagem de parâmetros.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>   

//Estava passando o endereço do vetorN e não o vetor propriamente dito.
//O forma correta é a seguinte:
void OrdernarVetor(int vetorN[], int tamanho)
{
    int i, j;
    int aux;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if(vetorN[i] > vetorN[j])
            {
                aux = vetorN[i];
                vetorN[i] = vetorN[j];
                vetorN[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}

//O dito acima se aplica nesta função.
void ExibirVetor(int vetorN[], int tamanho)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%i", vetorN[i]);
    }
}



    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

        int i;
        int vetorN[5];

        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            printf("Insira valor da posição [%i]", i);
            scanf("%i", &vetorN[i]);
        }

        //Na chamada da função devo excluir o ponteiro.
        OrdernarVetor(vetorN, 5); ExibirVetor(vetorN, 5);
    }
```